# Is constant SQL activity with Hangfire normal?

Tags: hangfire

Using Hangfire 1.5.3 with sql server. I recently put a trace on my database and notice there are various Hangfire commands running quite often, constantly, is this normal? I tried setting the QueuePollInterval to 60 seconds but that didn't seem to matter. I have ~10 jobs. most only run 1x a day, a few every 5 minutes or so. Is this normal?

[image]

**Update:** As odinserj points out, alot of this is from the dashboard.  However, I still see a good amount of traffic to SQL.  Anyway to control how often the heartbeat checks?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have dashboard opened in your browser.

Comment: Your right, a lot of these were from the Dashboard, I never put 2 & 2 together that could be it, thanks!